# DNS Error: AWS + nginx is allowing only one subdomain to pass through

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dns

I have started working on an already existing AWS + nginx setup. It was perfectly serving http://demo.domain.com

Simplified version of my problem: **I want to change serving url from demo.domain.com -> demo777.domain.com but urls are being restricted somewhere.**

For easier debugging, I have replaced the old server with a simple python server which runs on port 8080

```
<html>
           <body>
                   <h1>Hi! I am inside Simple Python Server</h1>
           </body>
</html>
```

I am serving this file through

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I can do a

wget http://localhost:8080

from inside the AWS ssh session and can inspect through cat index.html that expected file is being served.

Next I create an extremely simple nginx config and do sudo service stop, reload and restart nginx successfully. The config is below:

```
server{
        listen 80; 
        location / { 
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }   

}
```

Now from my local machine's browser, I do http://demo.domain.com and can see that the above index.html file is being displayed, as expected.

At this point, nginx has only one directive for listening port=80 and no restriction is there for server name.

Next from my local machine's browser, I do http://demo777.domain.com but I get a DNS error. Snapshot given below:

[image: DNS Error]

**Any pointers to places where urls might be getting filtered will be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: This is clearly a DNS issue, but you haven't mentioned DNS changes or your DNS configuration, whether you're using Route 53 for DNS, and what you might have changed in DNS.  Nothing about EC2 is "restricting" you, here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Thanks for the pointer. Indeed it is a DNS issue. Turns out AWS is quite different from Google App Engine. In GAE I never had to turn all these knobs manually. One just changes the branch name in app.yaml and it auto-magically appears on the web with proper subdomain. Bad conditioning by GAE:). Many thanks for the pointer Michael.